# Can Neo4j Cypher query do similar thing as "Having" in SQL?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

SQL has "Having" clause, for example:

```
SELECT LastName, COUNT(*)
FROM Employees
GROUP BY LastName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10;
```

In Cypher, we can do count()

```
START n=node(2)
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
RETURN type(r), count(*)
```

But does Cypher have similar function as "Having", or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, having is just one of the many uses of query chaining with `WITH` which is similar to `RETURN` but determines which elements will be available in the next query part. `WITH` also supports ordering and paging.

```
START n=node(2)
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
WITH type(r) as t, count(*) as c
WHERE c > 10
RETURN t,c
```