# Neo4j Cypher return only rows with count greater than 1

Tags: neo4j, cypher

First of all, I have looked at [Can Neo4j Cypher query do similar thing as "Having" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138752/can-neo4j-cypher-query-do-similar-thing-as-having-in-sql) and https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-achieve-the-equivalent-of-a-sql-having-clause-with-cypher/. They both have similar advice, but it doesn't seem to work in my case (perhaps because of the UNWIND clause I have?).

Here's my query:

```
MATCH (a:MyNode)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->()<-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]-(b:MyNode {prop: 'value'})
    WHERE a.prop<>'value'
    WITH collect(b) AS excluded
MATCH (m:MyNode {prop: 'value'})
    WITH excluded, COLLECT(m) AS superset
    UNWIND [n IN superset WHERE NOT n IN excluded] AS t
    RETURN t.propTwo, COUNT(DISTINCT(t.propThree))
```

This works well for me. The problem is that it returns thousands of rows with a count of 1 and just a few with a count of more than 1. I just want the rows with counts more than 1. Following the advice from the above links, I came up with

```
MATCH (a:MyNode)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->()<-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]-(b:MyNode {prop: 'value'})
    WHERE a.prop<>'value'
    WITH collect(b) AS excluded
MATCH (m:MyNode {prop: 'value'})
    WITH excluded, COLLECT(m) AS superset
    UNWIND [n IN superset WHERE NOT n IN excluded] AS t
    WITH t, COUNT(DISTINCT(t.propThree)) AS num
    WHERE num > 1
    RETURN t.propTwo, num
```

Unfortunately, this returns no records. I figured out that this is probably because the t values are taken one at a time in the final WITH clause (so COUNT(DISTINCT(t.propThree)) is always 1), but I can't figure out how to get over that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have an aggregate function in Cypher, think of anything not part of the aggregate as part of the group by in SQL. Instead of grouping by node t, it looks like you want to group by the value of property t.propTwo across multiple nodes.

Let's build some sample data.

```
UNWIND RANGE(1,20) AS idNum
MERGE (n:MyNode {id:idNum})
SET 
   n.prop = case when n.id < 18 then 'value' else 'not value' end,
   n.propTwo = n.id / 3,
   n.propThree = n.id /4
RETURN n
```

```
MATCH (n1:MyNode {id:3}), (n2:MyNode {id:19})
MERGE (n1)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->(o:OtherNode)<-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]-(n2)
RETURN *
```

This query will find MyNodes with prop="value" and give us values for propTwo with multiple distinct values of propThree.

```
MATCH (m:MyNode {prop:"value"})
WITH m.propTwo AS propTwo, COUNT(DISTINCT m.propThree) AS num
WHERE num > 1
RETURN propTwo, num
```

You should get back

```
propTwo     num
-------     ---
1           2 
2           2
5           2
```

Now we make the query a little fancier to check for a pattern `(m)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->()<-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]-(a:MyNode)`. If any `(a)` has a prop that does not equal 'value', we want to exclude `(m)`.

```
MATCH (m:MyNode {prop: 'value'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->()<-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]-(a:MyNode)
WITH m, SUM(CASE WHEN a IS NULL OR a.prop = 'value' then 0 else 1 end) AS exclude
WHERE exclude = 0
WITH m.propTwo AS propTwo, COUNT(DISTINCT(m.propThree)) AS num
WHERE num > 1
RETURN propTwo, num
```

You should get back

```
propTwo     num
-------     ---
2           2
5           2
```

Comment: You are correct that I'm looking to group by the value of property t.propTwo across multiple nodes. The fact that you could tell that tells me that I at least was doing something right. (I've been working with Cypher for all of 2 days now.)

Unfortunately, neither of your queries return anything for me. The first is similar to something I tried and I think it's running into the same problem as my attempt. I'm not sure about the second yet; I'm going to play with it and see what I can learn.

Comment: My mistake on the second query--I made an error translating it from the generic stuff here to my actual schema. It works pretty well--thanks for the simplification.

Comment: Sorry for the series of comments--the second query returns too many results. It appears to be including the stuff that I'm explicitly excluding in my query, so it doesn't work as a simplification of my query after all. Thanks, though--I learned by playing with it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Let's talk through what you're wanting to accomplish in English, and that might help with the Cypher translation. Is this right?

We start with the set of nodes with label MyNode and property prop equal to "value".

Next we find nodes that have incoming links from two MyNode nodes where one of the MyNode has prop "value" and the other has prop not equal to "value". The nodes with prop "value" should be removed our first set.

From our new set, we want to find values of the propTwo property for which there exist more than one distinct value of propThree.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better in English myself. That's exactly what we want.

Comment: Great. I wasn't filtering correctly in my first answer. I provided an edit that should work better.

Comment: The edit works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help and for the detailed explanation in your final answer!